# Can two functors be compared for equality?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

Is there a way for a method, which receives two functors as arguments, to find out if they are pointing to the same function? Specifically, having a struct like this:

```
struct FSMAction {
    void action1() const { std::cout << "Action1 called." << std::endl; }
    void action2() const { std::cout << "Action2 called." << std::endl; }
    void action3() const { std::cout << "Action3 called." << std::endl; }

private:
    // Maybe some object-specific stuff.
};
```

And a method like this:

```
bool actionsEqual(
    const std::function<void(const FSMAction&)>& action1, 
    const std::function<void(const FSMAction&)>& action2)
{
    // Some code.
}
```

Is there "some code" that will return `true` only for:

```
actionsEqual(&FSMAction::action1, &FSMAction::action1)
```

But not for:

```
actionsEqual(&FSMAction::action1, &FSMAction::action2)
```

Maybe this question doesn't make any sense (first clue would be that there seems to be nothing on the internet about it...). If so, could you give a hint, why, and if there are ways to accomplish something "similar"? (Basically, I'd like to have a set of callbacks with only "unique" items in the above-outlined sense.)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve where you need to make sure you have the same function being used?

Comment: Could you use member pointers instead of `std::function`?

Comment: the question could be a bit more clear. In the title you ask for comparing functors, but the problems seems not comparing two `Action`s, but rather finding out if two `std::function`s reference the same method of `Action`. How exactly do you intend to use the `Action`s? If it was a "normal functor" with an `operator()` you would probably simply provide a `Action::operator==` and be done with it...

Comment: Note that there's a difference between deciding if two pointers point to the *same* function vs. two pointers pointing to different functions that do the same thing. The former is just a pointer comparison; the latter would be more difficult.

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe it is an XY problem... I'd like to allow users of my class (which is basically a finite-state machine) to assign to each state a callback to be triggered when entering that state. If the callback is equal for two states, I want it to be recognized as the same.

Comment: @user463035818 You're right, it's about the references to the functions. Now that I think of it, actually I don't care about potential members in the Action struct, it's only about finding out which action it is. Though it would be nice if I could also call the actionsEqual method with lambdas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raw function is eventually a pointer. You can [dig it out](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) of `std::function` 
 with `std::function::target` and then it's simply a comparison of `void*`.

Comment: That's not that easy. It could be `virtual` functions which cannot be described with just one pointer.

Comment: No they are not.  A member function is something special.  You can't cast a member function pointer to a raw function pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver `target()` seems to work for member pointers as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76e4e6a1e58c8d97 Apparently it returns a pointer to the stored type-erased object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, Cool.  Missed that it was a function template so you could specify the pointer you want.  I though it was using the function type

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How about this? [Changed Demo of Cat](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76346dd8c3763782) ;-) (I'm not sure if it's rather a pro or con.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It does seem to be problematic if the `std::function` erases that it is using a member function: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73454764845dcb59

Comment: @Scheff `target()` returns a pointer to the storage of a `std::function`. Probably need to dereference it to get the actual pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yup. I just realized: If we use `target<void (X::*)()>()`, OP will be able to use member functions from one specific class. But then OP might as well use member pointers directly instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you elaborate / demonstrate this. I failed... :-(

Comment: @Scheff I mean the value of the pointer returned by `target()` is meaningless, you need to dereference it (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1677b3abcb0d34e) to get a pointer-to-member-function stored in `function`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you can try lots of variations like `target<void (X::*)()>()`, `target<Y(X::*)()>()` and `target<void (X &)>()` etc, which is slightly broader than one member pointer type

Answer (score 2):

Directly using [`std::function::target<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) as suggested in the Michael Chourdakis's answer is problematic, since to use  it you have to know the actual type stored in `std::function`:

> **Return value**
>
> A pointer to the stored function if `target_type() == typeid(T)`, otherwise a null pointer.

E.g. by using `T = void (A::*)() const` you restrict yourself to only using `void() const` member functions of `class FSMAction`. At this point `std::function` starts to be no better than a plain member function pointer.

---

I suggest writing a wrapper for `std::function` that implements `==` / `!=` using type erasure. Here's a minimal implementation:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class FancyFunction;

template <typename ReturnType, typename ...ParamTypes>
class FancyFunction<ReturnType(ParamTypes...)>
{
    using func_t = std::function<ReturnType(ParamTypes...)>;
    func_t func;
    bool (*eq)(const func_t &, const func_t &) = 0;

  public:
    FancyFunction(decltype(nullptr) = nullptr) {}

    template <typename T>
    FancyFunction(T &&obj)
    {
        func = std::forward<T>(obj);    
        eq = [](const func_t &a, const func_t &b)
        {
            return *a.template target<T>() ==
                   *b.template target<T>();
        };
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return bool(func);
    }

    ReturnType operator()(ParamTypes ... params) const
    {
        return func(std::forward<ParamTypes>(params)...);
    }

    bool operator==(const FancyFunction &other) const
    {
        if (func.target_type() != other.func.target_type())
            return 0;
            
        if (!eq)
            return 1;
        
        return eq(func, other.func);
    }
    
    bool operator!=(const FancyFunction &other) const
    {
        return !operator==(other);
    }
};


struct A
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

int main()
{
    FancyFunction<void(A &)> f1(&A::foo), f2(&A::foo), f3(&A::bar);
    std::cout << (f1 == f2) << '\n';
    std::cout << (f1 == f3) << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/576868113122ec76)</kbd>

Comment: I like your solution, and I will definitely keep it in mind for the future! I still accepted Michael Chourdakis's answer, though, since it is more lightweight and worked fine for my specific problem. Anyway, people reading this can decide on their own if they need your more general approach...