# Can two pointers to member functions be compared for equality?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692017/can-two-functors-be-compared-for-equality) earlier, but I realise now that it was not specific enough.

What I want to do is find out if two pointers to some member function of a class, combined with an actual object of that class, are equal in the sense that both will "call" (in the sense described below) the same function of the same object. Basically, in this code:

```
bool isEqual(F* object1, void(F::*_fct1)(), 
             F* object2, void(F::*_fct2)())
{
    TSpecificFunctor<F> specFunc1(object1, fct1);
    TSpecificFunctor<F> specFunc2(object2, fct2);

    return /* Something */;
}
```

Is there `/* Something */` that will return `true` iff `specFunc1` and `specFunc2` are pointing to the same member function of the same given object?

There, `TSpecificFunctor` is defined as follows:

```
class TFunctor
{
public:
    virtual void call() = 0;
};

template <class TClass> class TSpecificFunctor : public TFunctor
{
public:
    TSpecificFunctor(TClass* _pt2Object, void(TClass::*_fpt)())
    {
        pt2Object = _pt2Object;
        fpt=_fpt; 
    }

    virtual void call() override
    { 
        (*pt2Object.*fpt)();
    }

private:
    void (TClass::*fpt)();
    TClass* pt2Object;
};
```

In other words, the function should return `true` iff `specFunc1.call()` will yield the exact same result as `specFunc2.call()`.

EDIT: For example, this might be an application of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class TClassB {
public:
   TClassB() {...}

   void doSomething()
   {
      ...
   }

   void doSomethingElse()
   {
      ...
   }

private:
   /* Some object-specific stuff. */
};

TClassB test;
isEqual(&test, &TClassB::doSomething, &test, &TClassB::doSomething); // ==> true
isEqual(&test, &TClassB::doSomething, &test, &TClassB::doSomethingElse); // ==> false
```

Comment: first you want to know if the same method is called, then wether the call yields the same result. Strictly speaking those two are not the same. I guess it is the first you want

Comment: If you want to check the same *code* is called, then why don't you just check the address pointers? If you want to check the same *result* for the same *code*, then you cannot do that at compile time (unless the methods are `constexpr`) because every method could be indeterministic (having side-effects).

Comment: It's only about checking if the same code is called. Sorry if this was not clear. I added an example of what I try to do.

Comment: @Duke Well, then I suppose the *same code* will be at the *same address*. Just check the value of the pointer to compare the address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare two pointers to `F` instances, and you can compare pointer to members. This does the right thing:

```
bool isEqual(F* object1, void(F::*_fct1)(), 
             F* object2, void(F::*_fct2)())
{
    return object1 == object2 && _fct1 == _fct2;
}
```

Whether actually calling one or the other in which order yields the same resulting state is another question. If the member functions in question have no side effects, this is the case. But they could also modify global or somehow shared state.

Comment: If this works, it is embarrassingly simple... I'll try it out in a second. Of course, I was not asking about the actual result, I am only interested in knowing if the function called is equal.

Comment: Embarrassingly simple solutions are always the best :)

Comment: It works! Thanks!! :-) I though I tried that already, but my actual code is more complex, so I probably did something wrong...